# sed replace patterns except when it matches some specific pattern

Tags: shell, sed, matching

Does anybody know how to replace patterns except when it matches some specific pattern using `sed`?

For example, all "`foo`" should be replaced except for "`food`"

Comment: Why does it have to be `sed`? Post some sample input and expected output as this feels a lot like one of those questions that will evolve through a series of posted answers followed by "oh, that's not quite what I meant" responses.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/foo([^d]|$)/xxx\1/;ta' file
```

This replaces `foo` and the following character unless it is a `d`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to alternatives to sed, perl's lookaround assertions are helpful:

```
$ perl -E '$s="foofoofoodfoofood"; $s=~s/foo(?!d)/bar/g; say $s'
barbarfoodbarfood
```